# Any way to add **kwargs to __str__()'s signature of an object?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, signature, keyword-argument

I would like to be able to change the output of `__str__()`, and would like to add `**kwargs` for that.

Problem: it doesn't seem possible to change the function's signature.

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class my_printable_obj(object):

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.content = s

    def __str__(self, **kwargs):
        fancy = kwargs.get('fancy', '')
        return str(self.content) + fancy



M = my_printable_obj("Something to print")

print(str(M))
print(str(M, fancy=' + a fancy part'))
```

Outputs:

```
$ ./test_script3str.py 
Something to print
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_script3str.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(str(M, fancy=' + a fancy part'))
TypeError: 'fancy' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I notice that, despite the TypeError message, python did use `my_printable_obj.__str__()` (adding a `print('here')` at start of `__str__()` lets observe this easily).

Is there a solution to do that, or is just not possible for some reason? Should I then just better define another function, like `into_str(self, **kwargs)` and use `M.into_str(fancy=' something more')` instead of `__str__()`?

Note: writing this:

```
def __str__(self, fancy=''):
    return str(self.content) + fancy
```

gives exactly the same error.

Comment: You can add `**kwargs` to your implementation of `.__str__()`, but not to the standard implementation of `str()`. Consider using a separate method with a wider interface, like `.fancyStr()`; you can make `.__str__()` call it, too.

Comment: Yes, but will I ever be able to use something like `str(M, fancy=' + a fancy part')`? I mean, it will be possible to call `str(M)` then but I must use directly `M.fancyStr(fancy='...')` in order to use this `kwarg`?

Comment: I would use a separate method if you want to render a separate string based on the object's properties. If you don't care about the object's properties, I would do it outside of the object altogether, perhaps with using the decorator pattern, perhaps only with plain string concatenation. I'm not sure why you want to change what everybody expects out of `str()` to your specific example :)

Comment: You can make your own version of `str` (`mystr`) that accepts the arguments and passes them to `__str__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `str` is a `type`. When you execute something like `str(custom_object)`, the constructor of `str` call the object's `__str__()` method. You can't change the signature of the type without overwriting it (which isn't really a great idea).

```
class _str(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args:
            obj = args[0]
            if hasattr(obj, '__str__'):
                return obj.__str__(**kwargs)
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
str = _str
```

Yeah, clearly not a good idea, but here's the usage:

```
class Example:
    def __str__(self, **kwargs):
        return 'kwargs: {}'.format(kwargs)

print str(Example(), arg1=1, arg2=2)
# kwargs: {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2}
```

It would probably be a better idea to explicitly call the `__str__` method on your custom object, despite it being a "dunder" method.

Comment: OK, I was confused between `__str__()` and the _builtin_ `str()`. I clearly do not want to overwrite `str()`, what is required to do what I wanted to. So I won't, but thanks for showing the way how to despite the fact it's a wrong idea.

Comment: @steffen Overwriting a built-in type will be confusing to anyone reading the code (including your future self), and may be hard to keep track of which would lead to unexpected results

Comment: @JaredGoguon: Readability is an important point, undoubtedly. But if I only add functionality, the impact would be minimal and readability would not suffer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

The function that you are calling with the kwarg is [`str` (the inbuilt function)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-str).

`str()` does call the `__str__` method on your object.

---

Maybe what you are looking for is `__format__`

```
>>> class MyPrintableObj(object):

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.content = s

    def __format__(self, formatstr):
        return str(self.content) + formatstr

>>> m = MyPrintableObj("Something to print")
>>> '{: a fancy string}'.format(m)
'Something to print a fancy string'
```

Comment: Not easy to choose one of your two answers. But +1 because it's interesting too. (Another way of solving the case, though it's not exactly what I wanted to do, what is possible but not a good idea).